# Silex translation stops working when validation is registered

Tags: symfony, silex

I registered TranslationServiceProvider with YAML and it works fine:

```
$app->register(new TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'locale_fallback' => 'ru',
));

$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function($translator, $app) {
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new YamlFileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('yaml', CONTENT_PATH . '/locales/en.yml', 'en');
    return $translator;
}));
```

Then I register ValidationServiceProvider like this:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());
```

When I register Validation, Translation stops working. All strings that should be translated don't get translated with no errors.
I am changing locale in the countroller, so it might have something to do with it:

```
$en->get('/{slug}', function (Silex\Application $app, $slug) {
    $app['locale'] = 'en';
```

Comment: This might be a bug and I have an idea how to fix it. Can you submit a failing test case to the `fabpot/silex` repo on github?

Comment: @igorw I couldn't reproduce the problem on a clean install with just Validation, Translation and Twig services registered. I don't think it's a bug. Should I still report?

Comment: Only if you have a reproducible test case.

Comment: This may have been fixed by that PR: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/830

Answer (score 0):

So, all services (from service providers) get locales in runtime, before request, in create process. And, if real locale not presented, translator gets the fallback locale.

Problem: you can not change locale in runtime, because locale is a variable and not presented as link (if locale will be object, you can change locale).

Solution: Change/Set locale on request subscriber.